# Python subprocess.call gdaldem module

Tags: python, subprocess, gdaldem

In python how do I subprocess.call the gdaldem module for color relief?
In the command line I would type this:

```
gdaldem color-relief path-to-raster path-to-colorfile path-to-destination-raster -alpha
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not tried with gdaldem but with gdal_translate and gdalwarp.

Depending of your goal:

1. Single call on the os
2. Multiprocessing

Single call : os.system should be also used.

Single call or multiprocessing: I'm using a function to call my gdal subprocess.

```
from subprocess import STARTUPINFO, STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, call

def execute_gdal(cmd):
    si = STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    call(cmd, startupinfo=si)
```

Comment: Thanks! And about the [-alpha] argument, how do I pass it to the subprocess.call?

Comment: just add it to your command.

Comment: cmd_as_string = "gdaldem color-relief path-to-raster path-to-colorfile path-to-destination-raster -alpha"

Comment: execute_gdal(cmd_as_string) # execute your command